# Ember.js - Creating a "table" view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What I want to do is show data from a few models formatted as an html `<table>` tag. I am entirely confused on how to go about this.

On my page I have 3 tables that display info from a collection of models.

```
<div class="data-tables">
    <h2>First data table</h2>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Model #1</td> <td>description</tr>
    </table>

    <h2>Second data table</h2>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Model #1</td> <td>description</tr>
    </table>

    <h2>Third data table</h2>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Model #1</td> <td>description</tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How could I populate all three tables with their own models? The Ember.js TodoMVC example has an `#each` loop to go through all the models *of a single collection*. How do I handle 3 different collections of models?

I.E. first table is filled with `foo` models, second with `bar` models, and the third with `baz` models.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're looking for in an answer. Maybe a bit more about what you're trying to achieve? Or any pseudo code?

Comment: Modified as @claptimes suggested.

Comment: I have created a simple vanilla html table generator using ember here. You can look at the code and modify it to suit your need.
https://github.com/hrishikeshs/SimpleTable

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single model to populate the three tables with having all three models within a single model.
Jsbin link - [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/quzas/1/edit)